# tensorflow wide linear model inference on gpu slow

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow-serving, google-cloud-ml, tensorrt

I am training a sparse logistic regression model on tensorflow. This problem is specifically about the inference part. I am trying to benchmark inference on on cpu and gpu. I am using the Nvidia P100 gpu (4 dies) on my current GCE box. I am new to gpu so sorry for naive questions.

The model is pretty big ~54k operation (is it considered big compared to dnn or imagenet models ? ) . When i log device placement , i only see gpu:0 being used , and rest of them unused ? I don't do any device placement during training , but during inference i want it to optimally place and use gpu.
Few things i observed : my input node placehoolder (feed_dict) is placed on cpu, so i assume my data is being copied from cpu to gpu ? how does feed_dict exactly work behind the scene ?

1) How can i place my data on which i want to run prediction directly on gpu ? Note : my training runs on distributed cpu with multiple terabytes so i cannot have constant or variable directly in my graph during training , but my inference i can definitely have small batches of data that i would directly like to place on gpu. Are there ways i can achieve this ?
2) Since i am using P100 gpu , i think it has unified memory with host , is it possible to have zerocopy and directly have my data loaded into gpu ? How can i do this from python , java and c++ code. Currently i use feed_dict which from various google sources i think is not at all optimal .
3) Is there some tool or profiler i can use to see when i profile code like :

```
for epoch_step in epochs:
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(epoch_step):
            result = session.run(output, feed_dict={input_example: records_batch})
    end_time = time.time()
    print("Batch {} epochs {} :time {}".format(batch_size, epoch_step, str(end_time - start_time)))
```

how much time is being spent on 1) cpu to gpu data transfer 2) session run overhead 3) gpu utilization (currently i use nvidia-smi periodically to monitor
4) kernel call overhead on cpu vs gpu (I assume each invokation of sess.run invokes 1 kernel call right ?

my current bench marking results :
CPU :

```
Batch size : 10
NumberEpochs   TimeGPU    TimeCPU 
10             5.473      0.484
20             11.673     0.963
40             22.716     1.922
100            56.998     4.822
200            113.483    9.773

Batch size : 100
NumberEpochs   TimeGPU    TimeCPU 
10             5.904      0.507
20             11.708     1.004
40             23.046     1.952
100            58.493     4.989
200            118.272    9.912

Batch size : 1000 
NumberEpochs   TimeGPU    TimeCPU   
10             5.986      0.653
20             12.020     1.261
40             23.887     2.530
100            59.598     6.312
200            118.561    12.518

Batch size : 10k
NumberEpochs   TimeGPU    TimeCPU 
10             7.542      0.969
20             14.764     1.923
40             29.308     3.838
100            72.588     9.822
200            146.156    19.542

Batch size : 100k
NumberEpochs   TimeGPU    TimeCPU 
10             11.285     9.613
20             22.680     18.652
40             44.065     35.727
100            112.604    86.960
200            225.377    174.652

Batch size : 200k
NumberEpochs   TimeGPU    TimeCPU 
10             19.306     21.587
20             38.918     41.346
40             78.730     81.456
100            191.367    202.523
200            387.704    419.223
```

Some notable observations:
As batch size increase i see my gpu utilization increase (reaches to 100% for the only gpu it uses , is there a way i can tell tf to use other gpu too)
at batch size 200k is the only time i see my naive benchmarking shows gpu has minor gain as compared to cpu. 
Increasing batch size for a given epoch has minimal effect on time both cpu and gpu until batch size <= 10k. But after that increasing batch size from 10k -> 100k -> 200k the time also increase quite fast i.e for a given epoch let us say 10 batch size 10, 100, 1k, 10k the cpu time and gpu time remain pretty stable ~5-7 sec for gpu and 0.48-0.96 sec for cpu (meaning that sess.run has much higher overhead than computing of graph themselves ?), but increasing batch size further the compute time increase at much faster rate i.e for epoch 10 100k->200k gputime increase from 11 -> 19 sec and cpu time also doubles , why so ? It seems for larger batch size even though i have just one sess.run , but internally it splits that into smaller batch and calls sess.run twice because epoch 20 batch size 100k matches  more closely with epoch 10 batch 200k ..

How can i improve my inference further , i believe i am not usding all gpus optimally. 
Are there any ideas around how can i benchmark better to get better breakdowns of time for cpu-> gpu transfer and actual speedup for graph computation from moving from cpu to gpu ? 
Loading data better directly if possible zero copy into gpu ?
Can i place some nodes to gpu only during inference to get better performance ? 
Ideas around quantization or optimizing inference graph ?

Any more ideas to improve gpu based inference . May be xla based optimization or tensrort ? i want to have high performance inference code to run these computations on gpu while the application server crunches on cpu.

Comment: I would be interested in talking to you a bit more about this. If you're open to it can you email cloudml-feedback@google.com and reference this post?

Comment: @rhaertel80 : i emailed

Answer (score 0):

One source of information are the TensorFlow docs on performance, including [Optimizing for GPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#optimizing_for_gpu) and [High Performance Models](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_models).

That said, those guides tend to target training more than batch inference, though certainly some of the principles still apply.

I will note that, unless you are using DistributionStrategy, TensorFlow will not automatically put ops on more than a single GPU ([source](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/using_gpu#using_a_single_gpu_on_a_multi-gpu_system)).

In your particularly case, I don't believe GPUs are yet well-tuned to do the type of sparse operation required for your model, so I don't actually expect it to do that well on a GPU (if you log the device placement there's a chance the lookup is done on the CPU). A logistic regression model has only an (sparse) input layer and an output layer, so generally there are very few math ops. GPUs excel the most when they are doing lots of matrix multiplies, convolutions, etc.

Finally, I would encourage you to use TensorRT to optimize your graph, though for your particular model there's no guarantee it does much better.

Comment: is there an example of using my graph produced by saved model builder . all example/benchmarks , datalayout, i see for tensorrt are based on some image models

Comment: I think I missed this, so I sent another email

Comment: for tensorrt , can you point me to some example that takes a savedmodel produced graph ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any

Comment: i see , then can you possibly provide any code snippet or pointers ? . Do you even know if that works or not ?

Comment: This is the best I can find: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.7/tensorflow/contrib/tensorrt